# I want to remove milliseconds in the timestamp, and I want to convert the string to the timestamp in DataStage

Tags: datastage

I'm getting data like 2022-01-27 15:04:17.457000000, and I want to remove it after .457000000

I want the data like 2022-01-27 15:04:17 with timestamp datatype in DataStage

Data coming from the file

Can anyone help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the data coming from file?
Then read it as varchar and then use substring function.
Eg: inpcolumn[1,19]

If data is coming from database then first use 'timestamp to string" function and then use substring function accordingly.

Comment: Yes data coming from the file